# How to resize uiscrollview and its content on the change of orientation in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uiscrollview, resize

I am working on a project where I have added UIWebviews in the UIscrollview to show the description. I did this because I want to add the swipe effect to move to the new description page. Now, I want to resize that UIscrollview and its content (i.e uiwebview) when the orientation changes (i.e portrait to landscape or Viceversa).

Please give me any sample code or any suggestions for it.

Answer (score 1):

To resize the webview you have to write:-

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    webview.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * someValue1, 
                                        scrollView.frame.size.height * someValue2);
}
```

Comment: Exactly I am new for this field, but I wondered that If you don't use void then after it will returns the value to the main @shweta

Answer (score 0):

You can put your code in the following code block :

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
if ([self isPadPortrait]) {
    // Your code for Portrait
    // set frame here  
} else if ([self isPadLandscape]) {
   // Your code for Landscape
   // set frame here 
}
```

and following code will take care of orientation change :

```
- (BOOL)isPadPortrait
{

    return (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad
            && (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait
                || self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown));
}

- (BOOL)isPadLandscape
{

    return (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad
            && (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
                || self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft));

}
```

Comment: Thanks For it. I am able to detect orientation. But the problem is to resize the UIscrollview and its content. Plz help me at there.

Comment: You can set your frames in `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:`. what else do you need ?

Comment: I have only scroll view with me and I want to change the size of its content. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the autoresizingMask of scrollView and add this code to your .m file according to your requirement.

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * someValue1, 
                                        scrollView.frame.size.height * someValue2);
}
```

Comment: Will it  resize of uiwebview which is the content of that uiscrollview

Comment: If you are making the views in xib file than you can test it by rotating the view otherwise you need to make a dump xib file to check what autoresizingMask that is required to your application

Answer (score 0):

when ever the orientation changed

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration

{

// this delegate method will called if we set should auto orientation return yes;
when ever we changed orientation  so set frames.. 

}
```

for example

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration

{
    appDelegate.interface=interfaceOrientation;


    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)

{

//  SET FRAMES FOR LANDSCAPE HERE       


}

    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)

{ 
        //SET FRAMES FOR Portrait HERE              

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a similar question and their solution:
[Scale image to fit screen on iPhone rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219629/scale-image-to-fit-screen-on-iphone-rotation)

They used a combination of AutoresizingMasks and ContentModes for both the ScrollView and, in their case, an ImageView, although I imagine the same solution would work for your WebView.